# How to get test case execution of a test case with context of a Test Suite..?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-sdk-.net, .net-sdk, azure-devops-server-2022

How to get test case execution of a test case with context of a Test Suite..?? if the same test case is present in another test suite, I do not want it, its information is irrelevant to me.

I am using the code, but it is not behaved as expected.

I have also attached the expected output (image).(there are 2 test results present and it is correct)

By using the code, what I get, is also attached in json format, and it is not matched with the expected output. (I get only 1 test result)

Kindly help me out, thanks in advance.

```
    using System;
// Assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client.16.205.1\lib\net462\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.dll

using TFSRestApi = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi;

public class QueryRunner
{
    
    private void GetTestResultByPointId()
    {
        try
        {
            TFSRestApi.TestResultsQuery query = new TFSRestApi.TestResultsQuery();

            TFSRestApi.ResultsFilter filter = new TFSRestApi.ResultsFilter();
            //manual test so I set to empty string
            filter.AutomatedTestName = "";
            //test case id
            filter.TestCaseId = 1109; 

            List<int> pointIds = new List<int>();
            //list of test point ids
            pointIds.Add(1974);

            filter.TestPointIds = pointIds; 
            //set plan id to 1 b/c do not have plan id, i think it is not mandatory at all
            filter.TestPlanId = 1;

            filter.TestResultsContext = new TFSRestApi.TestResultsContext();
            
            query.ResultsFilter = filter;
            
            TestMRHttpClient testManagementHttpClient = new TestMRHttpClient(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/abc/"), new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential("extensionToken"));
            
            TFSRestApi.TestResultsQuery result = testManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultsByQueryAsync(query, "Project G").Result;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            DebugLogger.LogError(e);
        }


    }

}

public class TestMRHttpClient : TestHttpClientBase
{
    public TestMRHttpClient(Uri baseUrl, VssCredentials credentials)
        : base(baseUrl, credentials)
    {
        // Add the body of the constructor here.  
    }
}
```

[image: Expected Result, present on Azure UI, it is correct]

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "BuildReference": {
        "DefinitionId": 0,
        "Id": 0,
        "Number": "0"
      },
      "CompletedDate": "\/Date(1692709425060)\/",
      "Configuration": { "Id": "11" },
      "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1692709419570)\/",
      "DurationInMs": 5460,
      "FailureType": "None",
      "Id": 100000,
      "LastUpdatedBy": "<IdentityRef xmlns=\"schemas.datacontract.org\/2004\/07\/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi\"><Descriptor>aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/Descriptor><DisplayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/DisplayName><Url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Url><displayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/displayName><DisplayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/DisplayName><id>fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/id><Id>fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Id><imageUrl>_apis\/GraphProfile\/MemberAvatars\/aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/imageUrl><ImageUrl>_apis\/GraphProfile\/MemberAvatars\/aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/ImageUrl><uniqueName><\/uniqueName><UniqueName><\/UniqueName><url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/url><Url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Url><\/IdentityRef>",
      "LastUpdatedDate": "\/Date(1692709427647)\/",
      "Outcome": "Passed",
      "Owner": "<IdentityRef xmlns=\"schemas.datacontract.org\/2004\/07\/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi\"><Descriptor>aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/Descriptor><DisplayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/DisplayName><Url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Url><displayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/displayName><DisplayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/DisplayName><id>fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/id><Id>fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Id><imageUrl>_apis\/GraphProfile\/MemberAvatars\/aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/imageUrl><ImageUrl>_apis\/GraphProfile\/MemberAvatars\/aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/ImageUrl><uniqueName><\/uniqueName><UniqueName><\/UniqueName><url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/url><Url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Url><\/IdentityRef>",
      "Priority": 2,
      "Project": { "Id": "120ed16c-aa74-4049-ba94-90d8ef02a64c" },
      "Revision": 3,
      "RunBy": "<IdentityRef xmlns=\"schemas.datacontract.org\/2004\/07\/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi\"><Descriptor>aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/Descriptor><DisplayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/DisplayName><Url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Url><displayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/displayName><DisplayName>Muhammad Jalees<\/DisplayName><id>fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/id><Id>fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Id><imageUrl>_apis\/GraphProfile\/MemberAvatars\/aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/imageUrl><ImageUrl>_apis\/GraphProfile\/MemberAvatars\/aad.ZmIzMGExOGQtNTg5Yy03NGRhLTlhMzktNDhkODg4OWZhZWMx<\/ImageUrl><uniqueName><\/uniqueName><UniqueName><\/UniqueName><url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/url><Url>spsprodsin2.vssps\/Ab70c43dc-f213-4dda-b2a9-1d4777eeb08f\/_apis\/Identities\/fb30a18d-589c-64da-9a39-48d8889faec1<\/Url><\/IdentityRef>",
      "StartedDate": "\/Date(1692709419600)\/",
      "State": "Completed",
      "TestCase": {
        "Id": "1109",
        "Name": "tc 3"
      },
      "TestCaseReferenceId": 666611,
      "TestCaseRevision": 1,
      "TestCaseTitle": "tc 3",
      "TestPlan": { "Id": "1" },
      "TestPoint": { "Id": "1974" },
      "TestRun": {
        "Id": "91",
        "Name": "New Suite 4 (Manual)"
      }
    }
  ],
  "ResultsFilter": {
    "AutomatedTestName": "",
    "TestCaseId": 1109,
    "TestPlanId": 1,
    "TestPointIds": [ 1974 ],
    "TestResultsContext": {
      "Build": null,
      "ContextType": 0,
      "PipelineReference": null,
      "Release": null
    }
  }
}
```